# CodeIgniter Loading Database Error

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

When using Codeigniter to load the database, I am getting the following error message in a simple file where I load the database:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: database
```

The controller for this code is called db.php, and the code for it is as follows:

```
<?php

class Db extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('database');

    }

    public function index() {}

}
```

I do not have the database loaded in to autoload.php. I also know that I have the correct database information in my config.php file. My CodeIgniter application is in a subdomain if that might cause any problems.

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `$this->load->database();`? Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: will that perform the same as if I put $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); into my autoload.php file?

Comment: this is a good example: $autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database','email','form_validation','cart','encrypt');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$this->load->database();`

Instead of `$this->load->library('database');`

Comment: Yes, it worked but I don't understand why $this->load->library('database'); it's not working. It's the default way to load any library in ci.